# boost::spirit attribute assignment: struct is_nullary: base type fails to be a struct or class type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I have a `boost::spirit` parser that is supposed to simply assign a pointer to its attribute:

```
rule<CompoundExpression *(Scope &)> var_ref = var<CompoundExpression>()(_r1) [
    _val = new_<Reference<Variable<CompoundExpression>>>(_1)
];
```

where `var<CompoundExpression>()` is a just function that returns a reference to a static rule that does the actual parsing. I use the same assignment action with other instantiations of the `Reference<Variable<T>>` template all over the code and it's fine, except for the one that uses the `CompoundExpression` parameter.

The literal GCC error is this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/actor.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/phoenix/core.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/argument.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi_nonterminal.hpp:16,
                 from /home/ich/sync/ConTrAkt/gologpp/src/parser/utilities.h:7,
                 from /home/ich/sync/ConTrAkt/gologpp/src/parser/compound_expression.h:4,
                 from /home/ich/sync/ConTrAkt/gologpp/src/parser/compound_expression.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/is_nullary.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::phoenix::result_of::is_nullary<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::new_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<gologpp::CompoundType> > > > >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> > >, 2> > >, 2>, void>’:
/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/actor.hpp:178:13:   required from ‘struct boost::phoenix::result_of::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::new_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<gologpp::CompoundType> > > > >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> > >, 2> > >, 2> >’
/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/actor.hpp:271:9:   required from ‘struct boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::new_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<gologpp::CompoundType> > > > >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> > >, 2> > >, 2> >’
/home/ich/sync/ConTrAkt/gologpp/src/parser/compound_expression.cpp:22:58:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/is_nullary.hpp:115:16: error: base type ‘boost::phoenix::evaluator::impl<const boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::new_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<gologpp::CompoundType> > > > >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> > >, 2> > >, 2>&, boost::phoenix::vector2<mpl_::bool_<true>, boost::phoenix::is_nullary>, boost::proto::envns_::empty_env>::result_type’ {aka ‘const boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0> >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::new_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<gologpp::CompoundType> > > > >, 0>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> > >, 2> > >, 2>&’} fails to be a struct or class type
         struct is_nullary
                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Since that is virtually unreadable, I'll try to `clang-format` it. So I guess it comes down to the last line:

```
/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/is_nullary.hpp:115:16: error: base type
‘boost::phoenix::evaluator::impl<
    const boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
        boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign,
        boost::proto::argsns_::list2<
            boost::proto::exprns_::expr<
                boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,
                boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0>>, 0>,
            boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
                boost::phoenix::tag::new_,
                boost::proto::argsns_::list2<
                    boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
                        boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,
                        boost::proto::argsns_::term<
                            boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<
                                gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<
                                    gologpp::CompoundType>>>>>,
                        0>,
                    boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0>>>,
                2>>>,
        2> &,
    boost::phoenix::vector2<mpl_::bool_<true>, boost::phoenix::is_nullary>,
    boost::proto::envns_::empty_env>::result_type’ {
    aka ‘const boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
        boost::proto::tagns_::tag::assign,
        boost::proto::argsns_::list2<
            boost::proto::exprns_::expr<
                boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,
                boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::attribute<0>>, 0>,
            boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
                boost::phoenix::tag::new_,
                boost::proto::argsns_::list2<
                    boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<
                        boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,
                        boost::proto::argsns_::term<
                            boost::phoenix::detail::target<gologpp::Reference<
                                gologpp::Variable<gologpp::TypedExpression<
                                    gologpp::CompoundType>>>>>,
                        0>,
                    boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0>>>,
                2>>>,
        2> &’}
fails to be a struct or class type
```

Note that `gologpp::TypedExpression<gologpp::CompoundType` is typedef'd as `gologpp::CompoundExpression`

Now if I'm reading that correctly, this base type of `result_of::is_nullary` (/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/is_nullary.hpp:115) somehow happens to be a reference type and that is the problem. My `Reference<Variable<CompoundExpression>>` type seems perfectly fine, I can construct objects from it and otherwise use it as I'd expect.
Also the problem it seems is with the whole phoenix assignment expression, and not with its LHS or RHS.

Looking at boost/phoenix/core/is_nullary.hpp:115:

```
        struct is_nullary
            : boost::phoenix::evaluator::impl<
                Expr const &
              , vector2<
                    mpl::true_
                  , boost::phoenix::is_nullary
                >
              , proto::empty_env
            >::result_type
        {};
```

It seems to that somehow `Expr const &` (which in my case is the assignment expression) is becoming the `result_type`, which shouldn't happen. But then why does it and how could I be causing it?

Comment: btw, I know I shouldn't be using `new_` in spirit actions, but I need the polymorphism, so I'm compromising there for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You also shouldn't be returning rules from functions, mostly. But we don't have the relevant code to see what is the actuall issue. Try making a SSCCE/MVCE

Comment: Is it from https://github.com/MASKOR/gologpp/tree/master/src/parser ? If so, what revision has the problem?

Comment: It wasn't on github, yet, but I've pushed it now: https://github.com/MASKOR/gologpp/tree/vmatare/composite_types

Comment: To trigger the error you'll probably have to `cmake` with `-DBUILD_READYLOG_IMPL=off` because that part isn't ready yet.

Comment: Oh I think I've found it. I had a hunch it was something stupid. Looks like I forgot an include on the header side. But the error message resulting from that has quite the potential to confuse...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so it looks like I also need to

```
#include <boost/phoenix/object/dynamic_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator/self.hpp>
```

for the polymorphic assignment to work. Something I didn't notice because it was indirectly included in other cases.